# Twitter code: 89 Invalid or expired token

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I completed the 3leged Oauth and obtained the user oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

Then I tried updating the status by following this page.

```
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update
```

I submitted the request from postman and got the error msg

> "Invalid or expired token".

I have
1. Generated Consumer API keys: 
`(Key: "XXX" , secret: "YYY")`
2. Generated Access token and access token secret in "APP, Keys and Token":
 `(accesstoken: "BBB", accessTokenSecret: "CCC")`
3. Followed the page:

```
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth
```

and received the users oauth_token and oauth_token_secret:
    `(oauth_token: "EEE", oauth_token_secret:"FFF")`

4.In postman, under authorisation tab, I gave the following details:

> ```
> Type: OAuth 1.0
> ConsumerKey: XXX
> Consumer Secret: YYY
> Access Token: EEE
> Token Secret: FFF
> Signature Method: HMAC-SHA1
> Timestamp: 1575316381
> Nonce: 1575316381
> Version:1.0
>
> URL: POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hello
> ```

Comment: Can you make this clearer: "I completed the 3leged Oauth"? Does 3leged mean something like three-legged, or consisting of three stages?

Comment: To complete 3leged Oauth, I followed this page https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth